# SQL Server UDT and stored procedure trimming decimal digit values from .Net code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

We are using .net framework 4.7.2. we call a sp with User Defined type variable as its only parameter.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ABC] AS TABLE(
[A] [int] NOT NULL,
[B] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[C] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Value] [decimal](19, 6) NULL)
```

corresponding stored procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myUSP]
@data dbo.ABC readonly AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @data)
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable
      SELECT A, B, C, [Value] FROM @data;
END END
```

My .Net code is

```
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                    using (SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.myUSP", con))
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        using (transaction = con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
                        {
                            insertCmd.Transaction = transaction;
                            insertCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            try
                            {
                                SqlParameter parameter1 = insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", CreateSqlRecord(insert));
                                parameter1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
                                parameter1.TypeName = "dbo.ABC";
                                insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                transaction.Commit();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                transaction.Rollback();
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }

    private IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> CreateSqlRecord(IEnumerable<DataElementInput> entities)
    {
        SqlMetaData[] metaData = new SqlMetaData[4];
        metaData[0] = new SqlMetaData("A", SqlDbType.Int);
        metaData[1] = new SqlMetaData("B", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        metaData[2] = new SqlMetaData("C", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        metaData[3] = new SqlMetaData("Value", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
        foreach (Model myModel in entities)
        {
            record.SetInt32(0, myModel .A);
            record.SetDateTime(1,myModel.B);
            record.SetDateTime(2, myModel.C);
            record.SetDecimal(3, (Decimal)myModel.Value);
            yield return record;
        }
    }
```

I checked the value of parameter1 bvefore it is passed to SQLConnection and executed using ExecuteNonQuery, and it contains decimal values correctly. 
On other hand i also checked run my sp directly from SQL server management studio and it is inserting right decimal values in table dbo.MyTable.

```
BEGIN DECLARE @data dbo.ElementFactData;INSERT @data (ElementId,StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Value) VALUES(  1002, '1/1/1800' , '1/1/1900' , 0.786); exec dbo.myUSP @data;END
```

However when i try to insert records from .net code decimal value less than 0.5 become 0 and values above 0.5 become 1. Like 4.2 become 4 and 5.87 become 6

Anything wrong in my .net code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that

```
  metaData[3] = new SqlMetaData("Value", SqlDbType.Decimal);
```

needs to be specified with a precisionand scale.
So that it looks like that:

```
  metaData[3] = new SqlMetaData("Value", SqlDbType.Decimal, 19, 6);
```

Your CreateSqlRecord method should look then like this:

```
private IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> CreateSqlRecord(IEnumerable<DataElementInput> entities)
{
    SqlMetaData[] metaData = new SqlMetaData[4];
    metaData[0] = new SqlMetaData("A", SqlDbType.Int);
    metaData[1] = new SqlMetaData("B", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    metaData[2] = new SqlMetaData("C", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    metaData[3] = new SqlMetaData("Value", SqlDbType.Decimal, 19, 6);
    SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
    foreach (Model myModel in entities)
    {
        record.SetInt32(0, myModel .A);
        record.SetDateTime(1,myModel.B);
        record.SetDateTime(2, myModel.C);
        record.SetDecimal(3, (Decimal)myModel.Value);
        yield return record;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case somebody else has this issue, I applied the above suggestion, but besides that, it seems that when sending this data in a UDT (user defined table type) requires the number types to be numeric(18,2) instead of decimal(18,2). For some reason the system was rounding the value when using decimal type. Now with numeric the values goes as sent from the C# application. This is not the case if you are not using a UDT.